# Find out whether notification channel is muted by the user

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my Android app there is a long-running service (export data) which shows progress and ends with a notification for the user to share the exported file. To be clear, it's not a push-notification, but a `Notification` created locally by `new NotificationCompat.Builder(…).set…().build()`.

There are quite a lot of users which mute the notification channel (or globally disable notifications for my app). I don't know why, because it's really not very verbose, BTW. But those users feel like the app doesn't work. I'd like to warn them if notifications are muted.

Can I find out up-front whether a particular `NotificationChannel` is muted by the user?

I've only found `NotificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled()` but I'm not sure if it has another purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the combination of both the following methods to detect whether the notifications of a specific channel or the whole package is blocked.

From the Official Document

[isBlocked()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannelGroup#isBlocked())

> public boolean isBlocked ()
>   Returns whether or not notifications posted to channels belonging to this group are blocked. This value is independent of NotificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled() and NotificationChannel.getImportance().

[areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#areNotificationsEnabled())

> public boolean areNotificationsEnabled ()
>   Returns whether notifications from the calling package are blocked.

Comment: i think this doesn't actually answer the question

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a notification channel we can call the method `getNotificationChannel()` on the `NotificationManager`.

We need to pass the channel_id of the relevant channel.

Also, to retrieve a list of all `NotificationChannels` we can invoke the method `getNotificationChannels()`.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    List<NotificationChannel> notificationChannels = notificationManager.getNotificationChannels();
}
```

Now use your channel id to retrieve properties of that channel from the list. 
For example: if I created channel with id "Backup alerts"

Then I should check properties of that channels.

If you need to prompt user to adjust settings of that channel: you may trigger an intent from the app itself using Intents like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, notificationChannel.getId());
/*intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "Backup alerts");*/
/* Above line is example   */
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

We pass the channel id and app package name. This specifically opens the particular channel ID.

Hope that this may help you ;)

Comment: Thanks. It's not a direct answer to my question, but it's also very helpful to me. Now I know how to open the settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I find out up-front whether a particular NotificationChannel is muted by the user?

When the user "mutes" a particular channel, they technically configure the channel's [importance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#getImportance()) to [IMPORTANCE_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_NONE)

For example, to check if a channel is "muted", one can do this

```
val isChannelMuted = notificationManager
    .getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
    ?.importance == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
```

Comment: This does not work, always gives false

Comment: I'm using this in production

Comment: Some how it did not work, then started working, may be something i missed