# How do I make an Android local notification that doesn't pop-up, just shows up on the notification list?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am making a type of alarm app. I have a special alarm screen that I show when the alarm time comes. That works fine. But I also want there to be an entry in the notifications list if the user snoozes the alarm. But when I try to use a regular Notification using NotificationBuilder, it pops up on the screen at the same as my alarm activity (which is not full screen - uses transparency). There must be a way to get the notification into the list, so the user will see it there, but not have it pop up at alarm time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a low priority for channel you created

```
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW  or NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN
```

From Android Oreo, you need to use notification channels for creating Notifications.

For Example : When you create a channel, with id "Alerts" , 
you can define its properties like, its **importance** , sound etc...

The **various Importance Attributes used are as follows**:

**IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT:**
Default notification importance: **shows everywhere, makes noise**, but does not visually intrude.
*Constant Value: 3*

**IMPORTANCE_HIGH :**
Higher notification importance: shows everywhere, **makes noise and peeks**. 
May use full screen intents.

[This will keep showing over other apps and again like whatsapp message notification]
This works so because of its importance.
*Constant Value: 4*

**IMPORTANCE_LOW**
Low notification importance: shows everywhere, but is not intrusive.
*Constant Value: 2*

**IMPORTANCE_MIN**
Min notification importance: only shows in the shade, below the fold.
*Constant Value: 1*

So once you define a channels properties it could be changed by only the user through notification intent. 
Which i mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54199316/7039593

Using a low priority / min min importance may solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

This is done by setting the notification priority to MINIMUM.
For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "MyReminder");
b.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String id = MyApp.getNotificationChannel(context);
    b.setChannelId(id);
}
```

Note for Oreo and higher you need to also set the priority of the notification channel:

```
final private static String MyChannelID = "MyChannel_1";
private static NotificationChannel channel;

static private String getNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (channel == null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            CharSequence name = "My Reminders";
            String description = "My Reminders pre-scheduled using My app";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN;
            channel = new NotificationChannel(MyChannelID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
            // channel, if the device supports this feature.
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);

            channel.enableVibration(true);

            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    return MyChannelID;
}


static public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
    Context context = App.getContext();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    }
    else {
        return (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

I didn't check the behavior of every priority, but MINIMUM and IMPORTANCE_MIN work. If you have more specific behaviors you want to get, you can look at the documentation and play with other priority levels.

Comment: still notification is popping up.

Answer (score 2):

you use `setNotificationSilent()`

like this:

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("dasf")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("adsf"))
    .setContentText(getText(R.string.text))
    .setSubText("adsf" + " " + getString(R.string.bdt))
    .setNotificationSilent()
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
```